# Is it possible to execute ttcn via cli?

Tags: jenkins, ttcn

I am new to ttcn using eclipse titan.

I am trying to automate the execution of ttcn using jenkins.

Is it possible to execute ttcn via cli and generate xml results?

Answer (score 0):

just for reference for future visitors, this question got answered in the Eclipse Titan forums:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1078565/